# Why the WiFi broadCastReceiver dose not update the info received?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, wifimanager

I seriously do not know what i am missing in the below code. Wha t I am trying to do is, to have some `network` and `WiFi` info displayed according to the current connectivity and to the `WiFi` current state. For an example, if the App is running and the user decided to turn the `WiFi` OFF, then, some text should be displayed automatically to show the current `BSSID=00.00.00.00`, `speed= -1Mbps` `RSSI=0` and etc. And if the user decided to turn the `WiFi` ON, then, the same previously mentione info should displays its correspnding values.

To achieve this, I have created a `broadCastReceiver` for the `WiFi` as mentioned below in the code and I register this `broadCastReceiver` in `onStart()`, and unregister it in `onStop()`.

What happens is,

**Case_1**:

if initially the `WiFi` is turned ON and I run the App, then every thing is fine and the App displays something as in the `pic_0` below. But, at this state if i pressed the `disconnect` `toggle button` and pressed on it again to `reconnect`, then the App displays something like as in `pic_1` below and does not display the info.

**Case_2**:

if initially the `WiFi` is turned OFF and I run the App, then I get something as in `pic_2`, and this is normal because there is not connection yet. But, in this case after pressing the `connect` `toggle button`, i get something as in `pic_3`, and dispite there is a connection, however, no info are displayed.

Above that, when I run the App, and try to connect to a network manually and go back to the App, it crashes and `logcat` says `unable to unregister an unregistered receiver!!`

Kinly please let me know what I am missing and what I did wrong.

***Code***

```
public class WiFi_Socket_04 extends Activity {

TextView tv_conn_status;
TextView tv_wifi_state;
TextView tv_conn_bssid;
TextView tv_conn_speed;
TextView tv_conn_strengt;
TextView tv_conn_ip;

EditText et_ip;
ToggleButton tog_connect;
EditText et_msg;
Button btn_send;

private boolean isWiFiReceiverRegistered = false;
private boolean isNetworkReceiverRegistered = false;

private final String network_service = Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;
private final String wifi_service = Context.WIFI_SERVICE;
private ConnectivityManager mConnMgr; 
private NetworkInfo networkInfo;
private WifiManager mWiFi_Mgr;
private WifiInfo mWiFi_Info;
private final String TAG = "wifi_socket_01";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.w(TAG, "@onCreate(");

    mWiFi_Mgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(wifi_service);
    SetUpAllViews(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private void setViewState(int view, boolean state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(view) {
    case R.id.togbtn_connect: tog_connect.setEnabled(state);
    case R.id.et_ip: et_ip.setEnabled(state);
    case R.id.btn_send: btn_send.setEnabled(state);
    case R.id.et_msg: et_msg.setEnabled(state);
    }
}

private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mConnMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(network_service);
        if (mConnMgr != null) {
            networkInfo = mConnMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null) {
                switch(networkInfo.getType()) {
                case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI: 
                    if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                        setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, ""+networkInfo);

                        setViewState(R.id.et_ip, true);
                        setViewState(R.id.btn_send, false);
                        setViewState(R.id.et_msg, false);

                    }else if (networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                        setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Status: CONNECTED Or CONNECTING");
                    }else if (networkInfo.isFailover()){
                        setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Status: FailOver");
                    }else if (networkInfo.isRoaming()) {
                        setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Status: Roaming");
                    }else if (networkInfo.isAvailable()) {
                        setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Status: Available");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }else {
                setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "Status: No Default NetWork Connected");
            }
        }else {
            Log.e(TAG, "@mNetworkReceiverm(): ConnMgr is null");
        }
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver mWiFiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /*if (mNetworkReceiverState == false) {
            if ( registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) != null ) {
                mNetworkReceiverState = true;
                Log.i(TAG, "@onStart(): mNetworkReceiver registered, the sticky intent found");
            }else {
                Log.e(TAG, "@onStart(): mNetworkReceiver can not be registered, the sticky intent can not be found");
                }
        }*/

        int wifiExtras = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

        switch(wifiExtras) {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING: setText(R.id.tv_wifi_state, "Enabling..."); break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:

            mConnMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(network_service);
            if (mConnMgr != null) {
                networkInfo = mConnMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (networkInfo != null) {

                    switch(networkInfo.getType()) {
                    case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI: 
                        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                            setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, ""+networkInfo);
                            setViewState(R.id.et_ip, true);
                            setViewState(R.id.btn_send, false);
                            setViewState(R.id.et_msg, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            if (mWiFi_Mgr != null)
                mWiFi_Info = mWiFi_Mgr.getConnectionInfo();

            setText(R.id.tv_wifi_state, "WIFi_State: Enabled");
            if (mWiFi_Info != null) {
                if (mWiFi_Info.getBSSID() != null) {
                    setText(R.id.tv_conn_bssid, "BSSID: "+mWiFi_Info.getBSSID());
                    }else {
                        setText(R.id.tv_conn_bssid, "BSSID: "+mWiFi_Info.getBSSID());
                        }
                setText(R.id.tv_conn_speed, "Speed: "+mWiFi_Info.getLinkSpeed()+WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS);
                setText(R.id.tv_conn_strength, "RSSI: "+WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(mWiFi_Info.getRssi(), 5));
                setText(R.id.tv_conn_ip, getIPv4(mWiFi_Info.getIpAddress()));
            }
            }
            break;

        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING: setText(R.id.tv_wifi_state, "WIFi_State: Disabling..."); break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
            mConnMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(network_service);
            if (mConnMgr != null) {
                networkInfo = mConnMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (networkInfo != null) {
                    switch(networkInfo.getType()) {
                    case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
                        if ( (!networkInfo.isAvailable()) || (!networkInfo.isConnected()) ) {
                            setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, ""+networkInfo);
                            setViewState(R.id.et_ip, false);
                            setViewState(R.id.btn_send, false);
                            setViewState(R.id.et_msg, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (mWiFi_Mgr != null)
                    mWiFi_Info = mWiFi_Mgr.getConnectionInfo();

                if (mWiFi_Info != null) {
                    if (mWiFi_Info.getBSSID() != null) {
                        setText(R.id.tv_conn_bssid, "BSSID: "+mWiFi_Info.getBSSID());
                        }else {
                            setText(R.id.tv_conn_bssid, "BSSID: "+mWiFi_Info.getBSSID());
                            }
                    setText(R.id.tv_conn_speed, "Speed: "+mWiFi_Info.getLinkSpeed()+WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS);
                    setText(R.id.tv_conn_strength, "RSSI: "+WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(mWiFi_Info.getRssi(), 5));
                    setText(R.id.tv_conn_ip, getIPv4(mWiFi_Info.getIpAddress()));
                }
            }
            setText(R.id.tv_wifi_state, "WIFi_State: Disabled");    
            break;

        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN: setText(R.id.tv_wifi_state, "WIFi_State: Unkown_WiFi_State"); break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(TAG, "@onStart()");
    super.onStart();

    if (isWiFiReceiverRegistered == false) {
        if ( registerReceiver(mWiFiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) != null ) {
            isWiFiReceiverRegistered = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "@onStart(): mWiFiReceiver registered, the sticky intent found");
        }else {
            Log.e(TAG, "@onStart(): mWiFiReceiver can not be registered, the sticky intent can not be found");
            }
    }

    if (mWiFi_Mgr != null) {
        if ( (mWiFi_Mgr.isWifiEnabled() == true) && (mWiFi_Mgr.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) ) {
            tog_connect.setChecked(true);
        }else {
            tog_connect.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

    tog_connect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked) {
                if (mWiFi_Mgr != null) {
                    if ( (mWiFi_Mgr.isWifiEnabled() == false) && (mWiFi_Mgr.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED) )
                        mWiFi_Mgr.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WiFi is already ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }else {
                if (mWiFi_Mgr != null) {
                    if ( (mWiFi_Mgr.isWifiEnabled() == true) && (mWiFi_Mgr.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) ) { 
                        mWiFi_Mgr.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WiFi is already OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void SetUpAllViews(int layout) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(layout);

    tv_conn_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_status);
    tv_wifi_state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_wifi_state);
    tv_conn_bssid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_bssid);
    tv_conn_speed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_speed);
    tv_conn_strengt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_strength);
    tv_conn_ip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_conn_ip);
    et_ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_ip);
    tog_connect = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togbtn_connect);
    et_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_msg);
    btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
}

private void setText(int view, String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(view) {
    case R.id.tv_conn_status: tv_conn_status.setText(text); break;
    case R.id.tv_wifi_state: tv_wifi_state.setText(text); break;
    case R.id.tv_conn_bssid: tv_conn_bssid.setText(text); break;
    case R.id.tv_conn_speed: tv_conn_speed.setText(text); break;
    case R.id.tv_conn_strength: tv_conn_strengt.setText(text); break;
    case R.id.tv_conn_ip: tv_conn_ip.setText(text); break;
    }
}

private String getIPv4(int ip) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String result = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ip & 0xff), (ip >> 8 & 0xff), (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
            (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

    return result;
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Log.w(TAG, "@onStop()");

    /*if (mNetworkReceiverState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "@onStop(): mNetworkReceiver unregistered");
        unregisterReceiver(mNetworkReceiver);
    }*/

    if (isWiFiReceiverRegistered) {
        Log.d(TAG, "@onStop(): mWiFiReceiver unregistered");
        unregisterReceiver(mWiFiReceiver);
    }
}
```

}

**Pic_0**
[image]

**Pic_1**:
[image]

**Pic_2**:
[image]

**Pic_3**:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read the documentation about [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) to properly understand how they work. I'd do the following:

1.- Create an IntentFilter and register all the necessary actions that you want to listen.(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION, WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)

2.- Create a single broadcast receiver and add all of your logic in the onreceive() method.

The combination of WIFI_STATE_CHANGED, NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED and all of the parcelables they receive should be more than enough to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you for the answe, but step number 2 it is not clear to. is what you meant by single broadcasr receiver is something like uder defined receiver?if yes, which intentfilter i should add to it. thanks

Comment: I meant only one because your code shows that you are using two broadcast receivers which doesn't make much sense. You can use a single BroadcastReceiver with a single IntentFilter with all the necessary actions.